# How can I change the length of fe_users field in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, overriding, varchar, typo3-9.x, flexform

I'm using `TYPO3 9.5. LTS` and insert some `fe_users`.
The TCA input field `title` is to short for me, only 40 characters. I need more, so the value must be at least 255 characters (varchar).

How can I change the value of a TCA-field of an system extension or table from TYPO3?

I've tried to override `typo3conf/ext/myextension/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/fe_users.php` with:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['fe_users']['columns']['title']['config']['size'] = 128; 
$GLOBALS['TCA']['fe_users']['columns']['title']['config']['max'] = 128;
```

But after saving, I get an error:
[image: change fe_users values]

I also edit the field `title` in table `fe_users` from varchar(40) to (255) (-> phpmyadmin), database compare, clear cache, ... still the same error?!

Where's my mistake? Where did I forget something?

edit: 
I see, that my changes in `phpmyadmin` are not working. How can I change the value for that field?:
[image: phpmyadmin fe_users table change varchar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Everything like initial post ... additional insert into your own `ext_tables.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE fe_users (
    title varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
);
```

Now, the title has varchar(255).